# PHP for result into one string

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I'm trying to replace %filename% in my HTML e-mail template. What I'm trying to do is to send a e-mail like a notification of what files that has been uploaded. It works if I have everything in the same document, but when I'm trying to replace %filename% in my HTML e-mail template.

This works perfectly:

```
$date = date("d.m.Y");
$message = str_replace('%date%', $date, $message);
```

However, when I try to do this with all the files uploaded, I run into problems. I'm sure I can't do this, but how can I manage to replace %filename% with the filenames of all files uploaded? This is what I tried to do, and of course - no luck;

```
$filename = for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++) {
    echo '<li>' . $data['data']['metas'][$i]['name'] . '</li>';
}

$message = str_replace('%filename%', $filename, $message);
```

As you can see, I want all filenames listed with li like this instead of %filename% in my HTML template;

```
<li>filename1</li>
<li>filename2</li>
<li>filename3</li>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: your syntax for `$filename = for` is wrong. you can't set a for loop as a value for a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$filename = '';

for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++) {
    $filename .= '<li>' . $data['data']['metas'][$i]['name'] . '</li>';
}

$message = str_replace('%filename%', $filename, $message);
```

Comment: That did it. Didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative answer which might mirror your thinking. You're trying to loop over an array and return a result from a loop. While your syntax is wrong, you could look at [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) which can call a function of your choosing for each element of an array.

Thus, we can make a function which takes a single array of file metadata and formats the name as a list element

```
function listify($meta) {
    return '<li>'.htmlentities($meta['name']).'</li>';
}
```

Now we can build our list using this callback with `array_map`. As `array_map` returns an array, we need to `implode` it back into a regular string:

```
$filelist=implode('', array_map('listify', $data['data']['metas']));
```

You can combine this into a single statement, I've just separated it for clarity.

Comment: Great tip and great thinking. This is very useful too. Thanks!